# Wordpress twenty fourteen: Make separation between posts thicker

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to make the lines between the posts thicker and more visible. Right now they're very fine.

I tried this code, which I got the wordpress forum, but it doesn't work:

```
.list-view #content .hentry.has-post-thumbnail{
   border-top: 100px solid rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
   padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That should work, could you link to the site if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style isn't workign because none of the posts on that page has a `has-post-thumbnail` class, removing that will display the thicker border-top

```
.list-view #content .hentry
{
   border-top: 100px solid rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
   padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I will just ask the question. How can I make the margins smaller? You see in my page the margins are huge on left and right!

Comment: Which margins on the page?

Comment: I found a solution... Thank you anyway :) Cheers!